# SQLVDI and Backup Database event viewer errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

We recently started seeing SQLVDI and MSSQLSERVER errors poping up on a number of our machines.  Shortly after event 3197 (I/O is frozen on database x), we start seeing SQLVDI 1 errors (signal abort) and MSSQLSERVER 3041 errors, failure to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE. We run our backups once daily, and looking at our DB backups, they restore fine and are not corrupt.  But batches of these errors are happening throughout the day, with no logs of our maintenance plans attempting to run at those times.  Even stranger, we are seeing these errors occouring on machines that do not have SQL Server 2012 installed.  Any ideas as to what might be causing these errors? or if they can be passed off as nuisance errors?

Comment: It's some kind of snapshot, a VM snapshot, tape backup software or similar.

Comment: A VM snapshot would cause the databases to lock their IO?

Comment: Alex, yes it will. It has to quiesce the database files since they are open. It should happen very fast, but it will freeze I/O. It's why VM snapshots are not viable if your RPO is pretty low.

Comment: [BACKUP .. with SNAPSHOT will FREEZE the I/O for the database and report to the VDI consumer that the database I/O is frozen.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2009/03/03/how-it-works-sql-server-vdi-vss-backup-resources/)

Answer (score 2):

There's an external backup running via VSS (Volumne Shadow Copy Service), might be a VM snapshot, SAN snapshot or similar. It freezes I/O briefly to quiesce it since the files are open.

Reach out to your Windows admin for what's going on during that timeframe.

See [this related post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108538/i-o-is-frozen-on-database-also-i-o-was-resumed-on-database-on-daily-basis-in-l/108545#108545).